# If the velocity of an object is zero, does it mean that the acceleration is zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I am reading a book and the author threw the  question of the title for us to reflect. After he gave us some example to state that if the velocity of an object is zero it doesn't mean that the accelarion is zero.

"For example, when you put your foot on the gas pedal of your car which is at rest,
the velocity starts from zero but the acceleration is not zero since the velocity
of the car changes. (How else could your car start forward if its velocity weren’t
changing—that is, accelerating?)"

But for me it doesn't make sense. Of course I believe he is right, I just cannot understand it. I will tell how I see this situation. If the person pressed the gas pedal it will have accelarion and the car will move. In my head there's no "delay". I "delay" would happen if the car skidded.

Could you explain how the author sees it?

Comment: For what I understood from the other question, the velocity would be zero and still have acceration for a very short frame of the event. Is that right?

Comment: I think that the example of the "already answered" question is much, much, much better than of that of the book. Still the example and showed doesn't make sense.